# Why can't I seem to add buttons to a toolbar? [WINAPI]

Tags: c, winapi, button, toolbar

For some reason, as soon as I try to separate certain blocks of code into different functions, adding buttons (bitmaps included) to a toolbar isn't working anymore. Having them put together in one place however works like a charm, however.

Yet I can't figure out the reason for this. Maybe a pointer isn't working as expected...

The expected output is this:
[image: Working version with buttons in the toolbar]

The relevant code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            CreateUserInterface(hwnd);
            break;
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}

void CreateUserInterface(HWND hwnd)
{
    HFONT hfDefault;
    HWND hEdit;

    HWND hTool;
    TBADDBITMAP tbab;
    TBBUTTON tbb[TBBSIZE];

    HWND hStatus;
    int statWidths[] = {100, -1};

    // create edit control
    hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                         "EDIT",
                         "",
                         WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL |
                         ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                         0, 0, 100, 100,
                         hwnd, (HMENU) IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
                         GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

     if(hEdit == NULL)
     {
         MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not create edit box!", "Error!",
                 MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
     }

     hfDefault = GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
     SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));

     // create toolbar
     hTool = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL,
                         WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                         0, 0, 0, 0,
                         hwnd, (HMENU) IDC_MAIN_TOOL,
                         GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

     if(hTool == NULL)
     {
         MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not create tool bar!", "Error!",
                 MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
     }    

     SendMessage(hTool, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM) sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);

     tbab.hInst = HINST_COMMCTRL;
     tbab.nID = IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR;

     SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBITMAP, 0, (LPARAM) &tbab);

     ZeroMemory(tbb, sizeof tbb);
     tbb[0].iBitmap = STD_FILENEW;
     tbb[0].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
     tbb[0].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
     tbb[0].idCommand = ID_FILE_NEW;

     tbb[1].iBitmap = STD_FILEOPEN;
     tbb[1].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
     tbb[1].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
     tbb[1].idCommand = ID_FILE_OPEN;

     tbb[2].iBitmap = STD_FILESAVE;
     tbb[2].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
     tbb[2].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
     tbb[2].idCommand = ID_FILE_SAVE_AS;

     SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBUTTONS, sizeof(tbb)/sizeof(TBBUTTON), (LPARAM) &tbb);
}
```

What I get is:

[image: Here the buttons are missing]

The relevant code:

```
#define TBBSIZE 1
void CreateUserInterface(HWND hwnd)
{
    ...
    HWND hTool;
    TBADDBITMAP tbab;
    TBBUTTON tbb[TBBSIZE];
    ...

    CreateToolbar(hwnd, hTool);
    InitializeBitmap(hTool, &tbab);
    InitializeButtons(htool, tbb, TBBSIZE);
    ...
}

void CreateToolbar(HWND hwnd, HWND hTool)
{
    hTool = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL,
                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                        0, 0, 0, 0,
                        hwnd, (HMENU) IDC_MAIN_TOOL,
                        GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    if(hTool == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, "Could not create tool bar!", "Error!",
                MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    SendMessage(hTool, TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM) sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
}

void InitializeBitmap(HWND hTool, TBADDBITMAP *tbab)
{
    (*tbab).hInst = HINST_COMMCTRL;
    (*tbab).nID = IDB_STD_SMALL_COLOR;

    SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBITMAP, 0, (LPARAM) tbab);
}

void InitializeButtons(HWND hTool, TBBUTTON *tbb, int size)
{
    ZeroMemory(tbb, sizeof(*tbb) * size);
    tbb[size-size].iBitmap = STD_FILENEW;
    tbb[size-size].fsState = TBSTATE_ENABLED;
    tbb[size-size].fsStyle = TBSTYLE_BUTTON;
    tbb[size-size].idCommand = ID_FILE_NEW;

    SendMessage(hTool, TB_ADDBUTTONS, size, (LPARAM) tbb);
    ...
}
```

(Don't mind the status bar to the bottom right, I forgot to include it in the code in the first example)

For obvious reasons the problem must lie somewhere in the bit that handles adding the bitmaps and buttons. But what it is I don't know...what am I missing?

Edit1: To make it read easier I have removed the two additional buttons (less code). It works the same way still, i.e. not working at all. ;-)

**EDIT2**: Thanks to HostileFork I found out that a windows handle doesn't work quite the same way as a normal raw pointer in C. The solution was to pass the address of `hTool` to the `CreateToolbar` function:

```
#define TBBSIZE 1
void CreateUserInterface(HWND hwnd)
{
    ...
    HWND hTool;
    ...

    CreateToolbar(hwnd, &hTool);
    ...
}

void CreateToolbar(HWND hwnd, HWND *hTool)
{
    *hTool = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL,
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    hwnd, (HMENU) IDC_MAIN_TOOL,
                    GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    ... // and so on
}
```

Comment: Problem is not difference between `HWND` and raw pointer. Problem is that change the value of a parameter is never visible to caller.

Comment: That's exactly what a pointer is meant to solve, no? In that sense HWND wasn't working as I expected it to work due to the assumption that it would be a pointer like any other.

Comment: `HNND` isn't a pointer. It's a value. Think of it just as you think of an integer. It's a unique ID for a window. No other window in the system has the same HWND value. Now, the implementation may look like a pointer, and may be pointer width, but that should be opaque to you.

Comment: I suppose that's how I should look at it. I have no idea what happens with the handle within the OS when passing it raw (i.e. the variable itself, not the address) after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're assigning to an argument, which will only affect it for the duration of the function:

```
void CreateToolbar(HWND hwnd, HWND hTool)
{
    hTool = CreateWindowEx(0, TOOLBARCLASSNAME, NULL,
                    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    hwnd, (HMENU) IDC_MAIN_TOOL,
                    GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    ...
}
```

You need to either make hTool a return value, or pass it by reference or pointer so that its value can be bubbled up to the caller and used in the other functions...

Comment: I thought I took care of that by writing `sizeof(*ptrArray) * size`, which should be equivalent to `sizeof(array)`...

Comment: Oh, I missed that, just lined up "sizeof"s.  I have been looking at this screen too insomniacally long.  :)  Let me look over this again...although you might check to see if the behavior happens if you go down to 1 button etc. (which I would suggest would help make the code easier to read for us poor afflicted readers and possibly avoid such misreads.) :P

Comment: What do you mean? The size of the array is defined in a macro, so the behavior ought to be the same regardless of how many buttons it's supposed to hold.

Comment: I just mean that in terms of the creation of a minimal repro case, the less code you have to paste on the site...the better.  So if you get the problem regardless of whether there's 1 button or 3...it's better to paste examples on StackOverflow with just one button because it's less code to look at.  And if taking 2 buttons out makes it *start* working, then that's a smoking gun also.  It's why minimal examples are good.  (This is specifically tough to look at because it's parallel scrolling code areas, contributing a bit to my dumb oversight.)

Comment: Removed the two last buttons - hopefully it's a bit easier to look at now. :-)
Still doesn't work though.

Comment: Updated, better answer I think :) or else I really do need to get off the Internet!

Comment: Hmm, I thought, HWND was already a pointer type by itself...will try it, though.

Comment: It's a "handle", that you can consider it to be like a pointer.  But opaque: Windows doesn't want you to directly go look at the memory it points to, you use OS calls.  Yet even passing a parameter as a raw C/C++ pointer, if you want to change that pointer's value (such as to transition it from NULL to the non-NULL value after an allocation) then you have to pass a *pointer to that pointer*, which you dereference using `*` in order to modify the pointer itself.  C++ has "references" so you could just write `HWND& hwnd` in the parameter to CreateToolbar and it would work as you are intending.

Comment: No shit, this actually worked. You explanation makes sense, too. Thank you very much.

Comment: Passing the `hwnd` is fine, because you're not modifying the value within the method.

Answer (score 1):

Does `InitializeButtons` have a default value for the third parameter, `size`? If so, check what it is, as you don't appear to be sending this value in the call to the method.  My guess is that the parameter defaults to zero, so this will be passed in the `SendMessage` call.

If `InitializeButtons` doesn't have a default value for the third parameter, then either you have a typo in your example source, you have two `InitializeButtons` methods with different numbers of parameters (and hence are calling the wrong one), or your code shouldn't compile :)

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, otherwise the code wouldn't compile ;-) Corrected this.